# Location of Documents folder for an app loaded via jailbreak

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults, jailbreak, .app

I'm testing my app on a jailbroken iPhone. In my code I use `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]`.

I'm putting my app on the phone via SSH, and so it doesn't generate a folder in `/var/mobile/Applications`.  If the app were there, any use of `NSUserDefaults` would create a .plist inside of a "Documents" folder. Since my app doesn't generate this folder, I cannot find the .plist.

Where is the Documents folder of a jailbroken app, uploaded over SSH (in a .app, NOT .ipa)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OP asked for the preferences folder that stores NSUserDefaults. Check `/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/` for that, assuming your app is running as `mobile` user.

(Documents folder is a different thing, and is located in `/var/mobile/Documents`)

---

Note that, starting from iOS 8, these plist are cached in memory in the `cfprefsd` daemon, so overwriting files in this folder will have no effect unless you kill this daemon.

See http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Updating_extensions_for_iOS_8#Preference_saving for detail.

Comment: -_- I spent all morning looking for this and you've found it! THANK YOU SOOO MUCH :)